# Java jsoup table analysis either leaves out one row or throws an index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, jsoup

I stumbled upon a problem yesterday with the jsoup library.

```
public class Analyse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

        try {
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("E://eBot1.txt"));
            System.setOut(output);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fx) {
            System.out.println(fx);
        }

        for (int i = 1527; i < 1542; i++) {
            String url = "http://csgolive.eslproseries.de/matchs/view/" + i + "#stats-players";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String MatchID = doc.select("h4").text();
            System.out.println("\n\n" + "Spiel: " + MatchID + "\n\n");
            for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=tablePlayers]")) {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                    Elements tds2 = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
                    int vsTwo = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(13).text());
                    int vsThree = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(14).text());
                    int vsFour = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(15).text());
                    int vsFive = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(16).text());
                    int fourKills = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(20).text());
                    int fiveKills = Integer.parseInt(tds2.get(21).text());
                    if (vsTwo > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 1v2 Clutch: " + tds2.get(13).text());
                    }
                    if (vsThree > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 1v3 Clutch: " + tds2.get(14).text());
                    }
                    if (vsFour > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 1v4 Clutch: " + tds2.get(15).text());
                    }
                    if (vsFive > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 1v5 Clutch: " + tds2.get(16).text());
                    }
                    if (fourKills > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 4 Kills: " + tds2.get(20).text());
                    }
                    if (fiveKills > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Team: " + tds2.get(0).text() + " Player: " + tds2.get(1).text() + " 5 Kills: " + tds2.get(21).text());
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, i want to analyze a table from this (http://csgolive.eslproseries.de/matchs/view/1529#stats-players) page. In that URL, the matchID (in this case 1529) should be and determined by a for-loop. This works fine, so does the jsoup.connect statement. So I got the html code from the website. Now i want to filter out the aliases with the fitting team from the table. The command should be

```
for (Element row : table.select("tr"));
```

This, although gets me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:544)
    at org.jsoup.Analyse.main(Analyse.java:42)
```

I've tried methods to avoid this. The only working method is to put

```
for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)"));
```

This only load the table entries 2-10, so i always miss the first one.

**So my question is:** 
Is there any way to not get this error and still get all table rows?

EDIT: I coded another possibility which revealed the true error: The first row to be parsed at tds2.get(13).text() .get(14). etc gives the IndexOutOfBoundsException. So the first row is apparently empty. However when i print it to the console, everything is just normal.

Solved:

Replaced

```
for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
```

With

```
for (int f = 1; f < 11 ; f++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the table you are parsing have a header? As if the first row has  cells rather than  this would be the expected behavior...

Comment: This table has a header and a body. I coded another possibility which revealed the true error: The first row to be parsed at tds2.get(13).text() *.get(14).* etc gives the IndexOutOfBoundsException. So the first row is apparently empty. However when i print it to the console, everything is just normal.

Comment: You could try to print out the row on the console to see what's going on. i.e. print out every tr with less than 15 tds.